# Testing class function in JavaScript, Mocha and Chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have created a simple bot and want to test a basic class function called `getComputerChoice`. I am using mocha and chai to test this function but when I run it, it says `TypeError: getComputerChoice is not a function`. I have tried finding a solution but haven't had any luck.

Here is the code below:

game.js

```
class PaperScissorsRockCommand {
    constructor() {}

    getComputerChoice() {
        const choices = ['paper', 'scissors', 'rock'];
        const chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        return choices[chance];
    }
}

module.exports = PaperScissorsRockCommand;
```

game.spec.js

```
const assert = require('chai').assert;
const getComputerChoice = require('../commands/games/paperscissorsrock').getComputerChoice;

describe('Paper, Scissors, Rock', function () {
    it('Return paper', function () {
        let result = getComputerChoice();
        assert.equal(result, 'paper');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark you function as static

```
class PaperScissorsRockCommand {
    constructor() {}

    static getComputerChoice() {
        const choices = ['paper', 'scissors', 'rock'];
        const chance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        return choices[chance];
    }
}
```

As currently written you were adding this method to `PaperScissorsRockCommand.prototype`

Also testing a function that uses `Math.random` would be hard w/o mocking `Math.random` :)

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked but I get the problem where if it isn't paper, I get an error. How could I test it with the random as you mentioned @YuryTarabanko

Comment: You need to mock `Math.random` to return the value you need for testing purposes. Google "javascript mocking" For example https://blog.kentcdodds.com/but-really-what-is-a-javascript-mock-10d060966f7d